# Check if item of frozenset in list

Tags: python, pandas, list, frozenset

I have a dataset which exist of a column with frozenset combinations.

***Data***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'ID1': [frozenset(['a', 'b']), frozenset(['a','c']), frozenset(['c','d'])]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Furthermore, I have a list with letters, and now I would like to have a list with the index of the rows in the dataset where an item from the list appeared. So assume the following list:

```
lst = ['a', 'b']
indexSaver = []
```

I can work around this with a for loop, however the dataset exist of over 27 millions so I'm quite sure that it would save me some time to solve this issue.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for item in df['ID1'].iloc[i]:
        if item in lst:
            indexSaver.append(i)
```

***Desired output:***
In this case item a and item b appeared in row 0 (twice) and in row 1. The desired output here than would be *[0, 0, 1]*, having said, with a output *[0,1]* I could work as well.

Anyone a more elegant idea?

Comment: Given your description - shouldn't the desired output be `[1, 1, 0]` ?

Comment: Okay... I'm not clear how that `1` is present though?

Comment: I eventually want a list with all rows where an item of the list appears, so in this case that is in row 0 and 1. And in row 0, 2 items appear, therefore the two 0's.

Comment: except that last frozenset doesn't have any elements in common with `lst`?

Comment: Yes, but that was row with index 2.

Comment: @Tox I'm not entirely sure... but does `df.index[df.ID1.map(set(lst).intersection).astype(bool)] ` give you the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant the desired output is [1,1,0] but you can reverse the logic if needed

```
 df['indexSaver']=df['ID1'].apply(lambda f: 1 if  len(f.intersection(['a','b']))>0 else 0)
```

if you strictly need it as a list

```
indexSaver=list(df['indexSaver'])
```